# Is having a specialised PhD topic a pitfall when applying to be a lecturer of STEM education, even with relevant practical experience?

Tags: phd, teaching, stem, lecturer

This is in a similar vein as [What are the potential pitfalls of having a PhD](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/what-are-the-potential-pitfalls-of-having-a-phd), but where that was specifically targeted as entering industry, this is targeted at becoming a lecturer of STEM education (effectively a 'teacher-trainer').

Is having a specialised PhD topic a pitfall when applying to be a lecturer of STEM education?

To give an actual example*, I have completed a PhD in atmospheric physics (with a bit of programming thrown in) and 14 year high school teaching experience, I have applied to be a STEM Education lecturer - will that PhD be considered too specialised?

**note: this is just a real life example, not a self help question.*

Comment: @UV-D One more clarification -- are you referring to a lecturer the way it is generally referred to in the U.S. (as teaching position only) or for a position that also includes research? If it is the latter, you will be more competitive if you have education research experience (e.g., pedagogy research). I've seen schools that prefer their teacher-trainers have advanced degrees in education (EdD or PhD) even for the teaching-only positions.

Comment: @ChrisGregg thank you for that, I am referring to teaching and research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is having a specialised PhD topic a pitfall when applying to be a lecturer of STEM education? [with teaching and research duties]

I would not call it a "pitfall," per se, but rather you'll have to do some convincing that you're qualified to research in the field of education. I applied for a couple of similar positions (with somewhat similar experience and education as you, though with about half the number of years teaching high school), and the guidance I received was that I needed to demonstrate that I had a "research arc" (or research strategy) that was consistent with the research goals of the position. Having a good deal of teaching experience may have given me an edge as far as the teaching duties were concerned, but I only had one publication in the education pedagogy realm, and that (among other things, presumably) was not enough to make me competitive for the positions (i.e., I didn't get the jobs). In fact, it probably was the case that most applicants for such a position spent time teaching at the secondary level, and my experience there was a wash.

Bottom line: if you are asked to write a research statement, make sure it is highly targeted towards the position, and try to have a long-term approach to the research question or questions you discuss. Relating it back to your hard-science degree may be difficult, so leverage as much of the teaching experience you can to inform the statement.