# What are the most important get-aways from a PhD

Tags: phd, career-path

I have almost finished a master degree and want to continue to do my PhD in discrete Mathematics (Optimization/Operation Research) in Germany, but i don't want to stay in academica after that.

I would like to know, what are the main things you take with yourself, after doing a PhD except the title?

What does someone who spend 3 years after his master degree doing a PhD differentiate to someone who already started working in industry 3 years earlier in the same field ?

The reason i am asking is, because i want to know, what are the skills/qualities i should be focusing on developing, while i am doing my PhD.

Comment: You might want to also read [What are the potential pitfalls of having a PhD?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/what-are-the-potential-pitfalls-of-having-a-phd)